# Inject namespaced constant in another namespace.module.config

Tags: angularjs

I use the module organization with namespaces. Each module has its routing in `.config`. But I can't inject a constant which comes from another module (main one).

My constant `CRM.Config` contains all project configuration, such URLs, api key... This constant is inside `app.main`. I can't inject it in `app.<any module name here>`.

Some code:

**app.js**

```
var app = {};

app.main = angular.module('CRM', [
    // Tools
    'ngRoute',
    'oc.lazyLoad',
    'satellizer',

    // Modules
    'CRM.Navbar',
    'CRM.Auth'
]);
```

**config.js (generated by Gulp)**

```
angular.module('CRM')
    .constant('CRM.Config', {
    "project": {
        "env": "dev",
        "title": "CRM",
        "url": "http://..."
    },
    "oauth": {
        "client_id": "...",
        "redirect_uri": "..."
    },
    "api": {
        "endpoint": "http://..."
    }
});
```

Now in another module such as **auth.js**

```
app.auth = angular.module('CRM.Auth', ['ngRoute', 'oc.lazyLoad']);

app.auth.config(['$routeProvider', '$authProvider', 'CRM.Config', function ($routeProvider, $authProvider, config) {

    // Throws an error cause of 'CRM.Config':
    // Failed to instantiate module CRM due to: Error: [$injector:modulerr]...

    // Routing here...

    // HERE I WANT TO PUT MY CONFIG (NOT HARD CODED VALUES)
    $authProvider.google({
        url: 'http://...',
        clientId: '...',
        redirectUri: 'http://...'
    });

}]);
```

I heard that you can only inject providers and constants in `.config()`. So where am I wrong? Let me know if it's unclear.

**ANSWER:**

```
angular.module('CRM.Config', [])
    .constant('config', {
    "project": {
        "env": "dev",
        "title": "CRM",
        "url": "http://..."
    },
    "oauth": {
        "client_id": "...",
        "redirect_uri": "..."
    },
    "api": {
        "endpoint": "http://..."
    }
});

app.auth.config(['$routeProvider', '$authProvider', 'config', function ($routeProvider, $authProvider, config) {

}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you forget to require the `CRM` module in your `CRM.Auth` module definition, like so

```
app.auth = angular.module('CRM.Auth', ['ngRoute', 'oc.lazyLoad', 'CRM'])
```

This is working:

```
angular.module('foo', [])

  .constant('config', {
    val: 1
  })

angular.module('bar', ['foo'])

  .config(function(config) {
    console.log(config)
  })
```

Note, though, that the value of `ng-app` is `bar` when I tested this.

See this [Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/hParYKDmUWEVw1wzZU7E?p=preview).

Comment: I need a main module called `CRM` (ng-app) and its dependencies `CRM.<module_name>`.

Comment: You'll have to put the config constant in its own module, then. Also, why do you have a dot in your config object name, `CRM.Config`? That's not a valid JavaScript variable name. How's dependency injection going to grab it?

Comment: It's Ok to use a dot, as you can type `'CRM.Config'` and type in the function `config` or anything else.

Comment: The module name is `CRM` and it has a constant named `CRM.Config`. I can't see a module named `CRM.Config` in your code.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean regarding `CRM.Config`. I forgot that you can do DI annotation. I never use that. :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the order in which dependency modules are constructed. If module `CRM` depends on module `CRM.Auth` then it means that `CRM.Auth` is going to be instantiated *before* `CRM`. Only after `CRM` is constructed `CRM.Config` will become available. Of course you can still use `CRM.Config` in run phase of the application life cycle of any module.

See this [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/SIeKq38x3xdBMkhACLJ8?p=preview) for demonstration.

Comment: I don't get it, I load as: app.js, config.js and auth.js in this order.